# AS3/Flash: sort an XML dataprovider

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, sorting, datagrid

I'm using a XML file as dataprovider for a datagrid. Something like this:

```
<list>
    <Name date="06/09/2013">Olga</Name>
    <Name date="05/12/2010">Alfred</Name>
    <Name date="05/12/2010">Clark</Name>
    ...
</list>
```

The datagrid has 3 columns. Both of them are hiden (date and timestamp). Like this:

**Name** | date | timestamp

I'd like to know if it's possible to sort the XML based on the name before using it as dataprovider.

Cheers

Comment: why bother just use the datagrid sort on name when you start it up

Comment: dataGrid.sortItemsOn("Name"); Thanks.